# Обработка логики на игровом сервере

Tags: c++

Пишу игровой сервер на c++. Сервер содержит разные игровые режимы. Каждый игровой режим должен определять поведение при разных событиях или действиях игроков(пример: моментальное возрождение при убийстве на режиме 1 или ожидание начала следующего раунда при режиме 2). Где и как обрабатывать пришедшие от клиента данные(чтобы не использовать конструкции if, else if и тд)?

Comment: Вариант 1 - ссылочные функции. Вариант 2 - виртуальные функции,

Comment: std::unordered_map<Mode,  std::function<void()>>

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов ветвлений много.

1. switch - case
2. Ссылочные процедуры

   ```
   void (*OnDeath)();
   OnDeath  =  OnDeath_lv1;
   OnDeath  =  OnDeath_lv2;
   ```

   2.1 Массив процедур, разновидность 2.

   ```
   typedef  void (*TOnDeath)();
   TOnDeath OnDeath[] = { OnDeath_lv1, OnDeath_lv2 };
   ```
3. Классы с виртуальными функциями.

   ```
   class TManBasic  { virtual void OnDeath(); };
   class TManLv1: public TManBasic { void OnDeath(); };
   class TManLv2: public TManBasic { void OnDeath(); };
   ```
4. Массивы параметров.

   Некоторые величины, такие как вероятность нанесения урона можно заносить в массивы.
5. Использование шаблона. Данный способ усложняет понимание функции, но позволяет сделать несколько функций в одной. При этом так же будет немного путаница с варнингами, есть смысл если требуется ускорение, т.е. часть кода главной функции смешать с разным дополнительным кодом в одной конструкции.  Шаблон позволяет сделать несколько дубликатов одной функции, с разным кодом, при этом все куски кода с варнингами "код никогда не используется" - уберёт оптимизатор. Т.е. код будет вида

   ```
   template<int T> void OnDeath() {
     if (T==1) { // это будет скомпоновано только для 1
        }

     if (T==2) { // только для 2
        }

     }
   // вызов будет сложным
   switch (level){
      case 1: OnDeath<1>(); break;
      case 2: OnDeath<2>(); break;
      }
   ```

Comment: OnDeath должен вызываться после обработки логики. Ничего в голову не приходит кроме как создать класс IGamemode с виртуальными функциями, который на вход принимает параметры конкретного события(пришедшие от клиента) и при наследовании переопределять эти методы. Но мне кажется будет много копипасты в этом случае.

Comment: Если писать отдельными функциями - то да, будет много копи-пасты. Без копипасты - можно писать кучу if. Если хотите оптимизировать скорость - можно использовать template или #define последнее в крайнем случае.